# How to output a specific part of text in color?

Tags: java

```
System.out.println("You are currently at " + n);
```

I just want to color the 'n' in the output, n is an int which is already initialized. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Print (without println) the "You are currently at" alone, then print the n with the desired color (Not all terminals support colors). Note the you can use `System.err.println` to print it in red color (in Eclipse for example).

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't think the `System.err` advice is good. It may happen to look correct in Eclipse, but in a normal console it will not work properly at all (especially if stderr is piped elsewhere).

Comment: @DuncanJones You're right. I sometimes use it in eclipse to better see important outputs. I thought this might help him.

Answer (score 0):

Search around for "color control characters". Here's one link: http://www.linuxgazette.net/issue65/padala.html